# Pass scope and parameters to directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set a class in a ng-repeat with a directive.

I need to pass a parameter to this directive: `wineQty`

if I use `scope: { wineQty: '=' }` this works however $scope.bullet1Color is undefined in my html and thus doesn't affect the class that I want.

If I use `scope: '@'` I get the correct class however I can't specify `wineQty`

Is there a way to combine theses two syntaxes? so that I can access the scope and pass a paramater?

I've tried `{ wineQty: '@' }` but with no luck sadly.

Here's my directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('wineQtyBullets', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: { wineQty: '=', totalBullets: '=', numRedBullets: '=', numOrangeBullets: '@', bullet1Color: '@' },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // defaults
                var defaultNumRedBullets = 1;
                var defaultNumOrangeBullets = 2;
                var defaultTotalBullets = 12;
                var defaultWineQty = 0;

                // set values from attributes
                var numRedBullets = scope.numRedBullets ? scope.numRedBullets : defaultNumRedBullets;
                var numOrangeBullets = scope.numOrangeBullets ? scope.numOrangeBullets : defaultNumOrangeBullets;
                var totalBullets = scope.totalBullets ? scope.totalBullets : defaultTotalBullets;
                var wineQty = scope.wineQty ? scope.wineQty : defaultWineQty;


                for (var currentBullet = 1; currentBullet <= totalBullets; currentBullet++) {

                    var bulletColorClass = 'bg-grey';

                    if (currentBullet <= wineQty) {
                        if (currentBullet <= numRedBullets) {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-red';
                        }
                        else if (currentBullet <= (numOrangeBullets + numRedBullets)) {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-orange';
                        }
                        else {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-green';
                        }
                    }


                    scope["bullet" + currentBullet + "Color"] = bulletColorClass;

                }
                console.log(scope.bullet1Color);

            }
        };
    }
);
```

Here's my html

```
<div class="bullets pull-left ml15 mt6" wine-qty="wine.owned_qty" wine-qty-bullets>
            <ul>
                <li class="bullet"
                    ng-class="bullet1Color"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend this lecture: http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2014/02/19/angle-brackets-synergistic-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, by changing `scope` to `true` and accessing the parameters through `attrs`

If this can help anyone here's the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('wineQtyBullets', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var options = { };
                angular.forEach([
                    'numRedBullets',
                    'numOrangeBullets',
                    'totalBullets',
                    'wineQty'
                ], function (key) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(attrs[key]))
                        options[key] = attrs[key];
                });

                // defaults
                var defaultNumRedBullets = 1;
                var defaultNumOrangeBullets = 1;
                var defaultTotalBullets = 12;
                var defaultWineQty = 0;


                // set values from attributes
                var numRedBullets = parseInt(options.numRedBullets) ? parseInt(options.numRedBullets) : defaultNumRedBullets;
                var numOrangeBullets = parseInt(options.numOrangeBullets) ? parseInt(options.numOrangeBullets) : defaultNumOrangeBullets;
                var totalBullets = parseInt(options.totalBullets) ? parseInt(options.totalBullets) : defaultTotalBullets;
                var wineQty = parseInt(options.wineQty) ? parseInt(options.wineQty) : defaultWineQty;


                for (var currentBullet = 1; currentBullet <= totalBullets; currentBullet++) {

                    var bulletColorClass = 'bg-grey';

                    if (currentBullet <= wineQty) {
                        if (wineQty <= numRedBullets) {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-red';
                        }
                        else if (wineQty <= (numOrangeBullets + numRedBullets)) {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-orange';
                        }
                        else {
                            bulletColorClass = 'bg-green';
                        }
                    }


                    scope["bullet" + currentBullet + "Color"] = bulletColorClass;

                }

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: You should accept your answer as correct to help others :)

Answer (score 1):

Using "=" means 2-way data binding, and it's definitely fine.

The problem might be that your `link` function are executed only once at the very beginning, when it's possible that the values of your attributes are not yet assigned (may be caused by some AJAX calls).

I would suggest that you wrap all your `link` function into a `scope.$watch` function. Like:

```
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return { 
                    wineQty: scope.wineQty, 
                    totalBullets: scope.totalBullets, 
                    numRedBullets: scope.numRedBullets, 
                    numOrangeBullets: scope.numOrangeBullets, 
                    bullet1Color: scope.bullet1Color 
                }
            }, function() {
                // Your original code here.
            })
        }
```

Then your final result will automatically update if your directive got new attribute values.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work for me but saved me alot of time nonetheless, I had never used scope.$watch and helped me refresh certain parts of my view. Regarding the question that I asked in this thread I managed to achieve what I wanted, I posted my answer above.